# How to retrieve a file by UniqueId in any List subfolder

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, client-object-model

I would like to get a file by UniqueId inside of a `List`. I am not guaranteed which folder the file will be in so I'm using the `List.GetItems` call and using a CAML query to only pick the file that matches the UniqueId. My query is below but it isn't working and I'm not sure why. My hunch is that I'm using the wrong `Type` value. Here is my query:

```
<View Scope="RecursiveAll">
  <Query>
    <Where>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="UniqueId">
          <Value Type="GUID">37cf076c-32f9-4ea4-9ed7-04fea659d0f2</Value>
        </FieldRef>
      </Eq>
    </Where>
  </Query>
</View>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query, I've fixed FieldRef tag

```
<View Scope="RecursiveAll">
  <Query>
    <Where>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="UniqueId" />
        <Value Type="Guid">37cf076c-32f9-4ea4-9ed7-04fea659d0f2</Value>
      </Eq>
    </Where>
  </Query>
</View>
```

Also, I would recommend using tools like [CamlDesigner](https://github.com/chrisdee/Tools/tree/master/SharePoint/CamlDesigner), sometimes it is very helpful.

Addition:
As an alternative to CAML Designer, there are other other tools you can choose:

https://github.com/konradsikorski/smartCAML

https://github.com/sapientcoder/QuickCAML

Comment: Unfortunately the link to CamlDesigner appears to be broken now

Comment: @phuzi thanks for the reply I fixed it and add some alternative tools

Answer (score 2):

I would use `SPWeb.GetFile('GUID').Item` instead. If you know the ID I see no reason to do the CAML query.

**Edit**

For SP Online (Client object model) you can use:

```
Web.GetFileById
```

as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.getfilebyid(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: I don't have that method available. I'm using the 2013 dlls, could that be why?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the Online flag in your post. This works in on-prem